# Array following Curve, but doesn't start on the first vertex of Curve

Tags: curve-modifier

I have curve which should wrap bat, however, when I attach wire and those knives to curve, they don't start on first vertex of the curve neither end on the last one. Also, when I attach wire and knives to the curve they appear very strecthed or shrinked.

I put all origins on the same point, they are scaled evenly, but I am doing something wrong because I always have this problem with curve. Here is blend file so be free to check.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While origins are aligned, the geometry isn't ;)
You need to move it to the origin point as well

[image]

Comment: ...and do the same with the knifes too ;)

Comment: I didn't know I am supposed to do that :D thanks, now it's better

Comment: Happy to help :) Working with curves is sometimes kinda finicky ;)